# run gulp task in mocha test lead to timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, mocha.js

Full code can be found in [here](https://github.com/cgcgbcbc/gulp-chroot)

And the failed test is:

```
it('should work with promise', function(done) {
  gulp.chroot('child', function() {
  gulp.task('promise', function() {
    return gulp.src('test.txt')
            .pipe(through2.obj(function(){
              console.log('inside promise task');
              console.log(process.cwd());
              assert.equal(process.cwd(), path.join(__dirname, 'child'));
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(__dirname, 'child', '2.txt')));
    });
  });
  gulp.task('sync', ['promise'], function() {
    console.log('inside sync');
    done();
  });
  gulp.start('sync');
});
```

This test will timeout, why? And `inside sync` never print

Comment: What does this have to do with ES6 or promises?

Answer (score 0):

The inside of you gulp task is never reached, so done(); is never reached - therefore there's no callback and it times out.